# Variable content in Notebook Dashboard (what is the templating system?)

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm modifying the template for my Notebooks.

Taking the ideas used in https://github.com/jupyter/docker-demo-images I can hack a modification the template, and even add some static html to the dashboard..... but I don't know *why* it's working, nor *how* it's working

What I'd like to do now is add content based on some variable defined externally - which could be part of the user-options passed into the hub, or as an environment variable.

So my question is partly *what is the templating system* (so I can try & figure out the solution myself), and partly *how do I read an externally set variable, and how should I set that variable* (so I can be lazy, and not learn about the templating system.)

Thank you...

Comment: Part 2: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710040/discovering-which-kernel-has-been-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1: Templating system is called Jinji (http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

No solution to part 2 yet