# discovering which kernel has been started

Tags: jupyter-notebook

**Environment** : I am spawning Notebook Servers (version 5) in Docker Containers, and have a system where users may select one of several Notebook kernels (thus, docker images) they wish to start.

I have a need to add an indicator to the *notebook server* page to indicate which particular kernel has been started.

I already have templates that modify the `page.html` and `tree.html` templates, so can add whatever I need into the *html* no problem.... what I'm failing to work out is how I get some piece of data from the Docker Container to the Notebook Server rendering code.

I'm deducing that it will probably be by adding something to the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file - but can't find anything to help either way.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to the Jupyter development peoples... I have a solution:

### Passing data in

In `jupyter_notebook_config.py` you can set a dict:

```
c.NotebookApp.jinja_template_vars = {'Ian_1':'One','ian_2':'Two'}
```

### Reading data in the templates

In your Jinja template file, there's probably a block for getting parameters. In `tree.html` it looks like this:

```
{% block params %}
{{super()}}
data-base-url="{{base_url | urlencode}}"
data-notebook-path="{{notebook_path | urlencode}}"
data-terminals-available="{{terminals_available}}"
data-server-root="{{server_root}}"
{% endblock %}
```

All you need to do it add in your variables (obviously, they are case-sensitive).... eg:

```
{% block params %}
{{super()}}
data-base-url="{{base_url | urlencode}}"
data-notebook-path="{{notebook_path | urlencode}}"
data-terminals-available="{{terminals_available}}"
data-server-root="{{server_root}}"
ian_1="{{ian_1}}"
ian_2="{{ian_2}}"
{% endblock %}
```

(note the incorrect case-match for `Ian_1`)

if you now look at the source code of the `/tree` page in your notebook, you'll find them as *attributes* to the `body` tag:

```
<body class=""
     data-jupyter-api-token="<token-string>"
     data-base-url="/"
     data-notebook-path=""
     data-terminals-available="True"
     data-server-root="/home/jovyan"
     ian_1=""
     ian_2="Two"
     dir="ltr">
```

(and note that `ian_1` is blank due to the case mis-match.)

### Using variables

You can now use the variable as any other variable in Jinja (as per http://jinja.pocoo.org/)